# What is the XETH Wallet / Bitprofile?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, clients

What is the [XETH Wallet?](https://web.archive.org/web/20161115125703/http://bitprofile.github.io:80/xeth/) I see it's some kind of wallet dapp on top of a geth instance.

[image]

But what is the Bitprofile and what makes it different to other wallets like Mist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like they claim,

> Xeth is a free, open-source Ethereum GUI wallet. It implements various useful features, like stealth payments, bitprofile support, secure random key generation, addressbook and much more.

**BITPROFILE**

> BitProfile is a decentralized user namespace system which allows to receive direct payments anonymously.

#### The difference is that, Xeth have added all the features of a wallet along with this BITPROFILE support.

Comment: is this a legit thing? do you know the team?

Comment: @RolandKofler do i dont know the team. and that question is out of topic if ESE.

Comment: Does this Xeth require the Bitprofile server? or it will work as a normal wallet with the addition of connecting to the bitprofile service?

Answer (score 0):

It implements stealth payments among other features.